# Yii ClistView Pagination set number of page shown in Pager

Tags: yii, pagination

Hi think this is a quite easy problem, but I can't find the solution in the docs. I'm using Yii ClistView to paginate my results and everything works great, simply (as I could have a lot of results) I would like to limit non the result but the page shown in the navigation (that are ten by default) to let's say 4. But I won't limit the number of my results, just when I reach the 4th page the navigation will slide (as its default behavior) to show page 5, 6, ecc...

Is this possible? Does anyone have advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about setting pager's maxButtonCount like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    // ...
    'pager' => array('maxButtonCount' => 4),
));
```